# Concatenating the Razor Variables with CSS Styles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to concatenate the Razor Variable (int) with a CSS Style so I can display the background image.

```
@{
    var positionY = 0; 
}

@foreach (var img in Model.Images)
{
    <div style="background-image: url('@Model.SpriteSheetUrl'); width: 60px; height: 60px;background-position: 0px @positionY px)> </div>



    positionY += 60; 

}
```

The problem I am facing is with the following line:

```
@positionY px
```

This produces 60 px (Notice the space between 60 and px) That space is causing the issue. How can I eliminate that space so it reads 60px instead of 60 px.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('@Model.SpriteSheetUrl'); width: 60px; height: 60px;background-position: 0px @(positionY + "px"))> </div>
```

The `@()` renders whatever is written inside of it as a literal, so you should get "60px" as the output.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer in few minutes when StackOverFlow allows me :) Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure you mean "literal"? positionY is not a literal but a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario where the model property is only part of the url and must be preceded by an extension. The escape character must be used to concatenate the extension.

<div style="color:white;text-align:center;width:24px;background-image:url('../../images/@item.Color\.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:left;background-size:100%;">